# Convert react native app to web using Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation

I converted React Native app to web app using react-native-web, but there is a problem to convert Navigator. Does anyone know how to convert it or replace it with something familiar so I can use it on my web app ?

Comment: I think you can found informations about the problem here https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/29

Comment: I saw that page but all links there are dead.

Comment: https://github.com/rhinos-app/rhinos-app-dev/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing we've found that provides a single navigation interface across all three platforms is [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). Otherwise, you're looking at using one router for web and another for native. Possible, but very sub-optimal.

The downside is that to support all three platforms, you sort-of have to work from the lowest-common-denominator, which is the native style of creating imperative navigation stacks. If you're used to react-router, or the Angular router, you won't love it. And... it's still an early project, with some gaps in docs, api, etc. On the other hand, it's [backed by some central players](https://adtmag.com/articles/2017/01/27/react-navigation.aspx) behind React-Native, and is progressing quickly. And it works.

Comment: The maintainers of React Navigator have stated that react-navigation does not work with react-native-web. Some have gotten it to work but only partially and with black magic.

Comment: You're on-point @raarts, but I wouldn't exactly call it 'black magic.' You simply have to create your own bindings to unify the root-level abstractions for React-Native and those for Web. That requires a little more depth on the underlying APIs and data-types than some folks may want to acquire, but is a lot less work than maintaining two separate navigation stacks inside the same application.

Hopefully, a library will fill this gap, but I can't say we like our own patterns enough to impose them on others. :-) Also, I continue to hope that R-N itself will pick it up.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I am currently working with the React Navigation (and Expo)  people to add support for react-native-web.